# IPhone : How can I prevent inserting text if the text exceeds the size of a UITextview

Tags: iphone, text, uitextview, limit

I have a UITextView, the size of which is set through setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 273, 140).

I would like to prevent inserting text that exceeds the size of the TextView.

So I've tried :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
if ((textView.contentOffset.y + textView.frame.size.height) < textView.contentSize.height){
    return NO;
}
else {
    return YES;
}
return YES;
}
```

The pb is that when the condition is met, I can't use backspace to erase the extra text. The textview is no longer editable. What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found out by myself this time.

I don't know if it is the best solution but it works fine at least.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)uiViewContent{
if ((uiViewContent.contentOffset.y + uiViewContent.frame.size.height) < self.entryTextField2.contentSize.height){
self.entryTextField2.text=[self.entryTextField2.text substringToIndex:[self.entryTextField2.text length] - 1];
 }
}
```

Hope it may help someone...

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something similar to this? I wrote it real quick and haven't tested it out. Let me know if it works. I don't know off the top of my head anything about the fonts, so you'll have to do some reading and adjust the code accordingly, where it says *whateveryourfontis*

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    NSSTring *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textView.text, text];
    CGSize *newSize = [newString sizeWithFont: [UIFont _whateveryourfontis_] constrainedToSize:textView.frame.size];
    return (newSize.height > textView.frame.size.height) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have read your code and your solution consists in adapting the size of the font in order to make the text fit into the UIView, but actually, I don't want to change the size of the font, the text inside the UITextView will be displayed in a UIAlertview over which I have no control since it will be launched by an UILocalNotification. What I need to do is to make sure that once the user reaches the end of the UITextView, he cannot add more characters while being able to use backspace to remove any extra character or rephrase the content of the UItextView.